# remove desktop/trash shortcut from thunar (xfce)

Tags: xfce, thunar

I use Linux Mint 21 XFCE.  By default the file manager thunar has shortcuts for the desktop folder and the trash folder.  I am not able to move/delete these two by right-clicking on the shortcut so I can with the other shortcuts.  What can I do to (1) delete the desktop shortcut, and (2) move the trash shortcut to the bottom of the list of shortcuts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[XFCE does not allow you to delete the trash can](https://wiki.xfce.org/faq#file_manager). You can, however, disable desktop shortcuts by right-clicking on the desktop > Desktop Settings > Icons > Default Icons > Deselect the ones that you don't want.

As for the second, I'm not entirely sure, since I haven't used XFCE in a very long time.

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the sidebar and then deselect the places you don't want.